# LyX AMS align environment justification/ horizontal alignment

Tags: math-mode, align, lyx, horizontal-alignment

I'd like to know how to justify individual columns in the AMS align environment. In the matrix environment, the Table toolbar buttons are active, but not inside the AMS align environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment of the columns of an align environment is fixed. It's like `rl` for each pair of columns. That's why the toolbar buttons are disabled.

If you would like to have different adjustment, you could use an array environment, especially if you don't need numbered rows.

However, you may change the alignment by placing the `&` symbol differently. This might be better with alignat instead of align.